# My jQuery UI datepicker won't show if the element has ever been hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

A little context: I'm creating a wizard, so the content of a step is hidden until you're up to that step. I'm dynamically creating the second step of the form based on your input from the first step, like so:

### No Hiding, Get Input, Show Output

#### HTML

```
    <p class="par">
        <label for="report_cat">Category:</label>
        <span class="field">
            <select data-bind="options: reportTypes, optionsText: 'title', value: selectedReportType, optionsCaption: 'Report Category'" id="report_cat" class="longinput"></select>
        </span>
    </p>
    <p class="par">
        <label for="report">Report:</label>
        <span class="field">
            <select data-bind="options: reportPool, optionsText: 'title', value: selectedReport, optionsCaption: 'Select Report'" id="report" class="longinput"></select>
        </span>
    </p>
    <div class="widgetcontent stdform stdform2 stdformwidget" id="tmptest" data-bind="wizardInputs: inputPool">
    </div>
```

#### Relevant Javascript (ReportTypes is just an array of javascript objects)

```
self.inputPool = ko.computed(function() {
if (self.selectedReport() == null) return [];

//set the url
self.postUrl(self.selectedReport().postUrl);

var inputs = self.selectedReport().inputs.map(function(elem) {
    var element = null;
    var type = elem["type"];
    var id = "wizard-elem-" + elem["title"].replace(/\s+/g, '');

    if (type == "date") {
        element = $("<input type =\"text\" id=\"" + id + "\" class=\"longinput wizard-dp\" style=\"display:inline-block\" />");
        element.datepicker();
    }
    if (type == "checkbox") {
        element = $("<input type =\"checkbox\" id=\"" + id + "\" />");
    }
    if (type == "select") {
        //do something with options
        element = $("<input type =\"checkbox\" id=\"" + id + "\" />");
    }

    elem["elem"] = element;
    return elem;
});

return inputs;
});

ko.bindingHandlers.wizardInputs = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var ele = $(element);
        var value = valueAccessor();
        ele.children(".wizardContent").remove();
        var container = $("<div class=\"wizardContent\"></div>");

        for (var x in value()) {
            var single = value()[x];
            var id = "wizard-elem-final-" + single["title"].replace(/\s+/g, '');
            var param = $("<p></p>").addClass("par");
            param.append("<label for=\"" + id + "\">" + single["title"] + "</label>");
            var field = $("<span></span>").addClass("field");
            field.append(single["elem"]);
            param.append(field);
            container.append(param);
        }

    if (value().length > 0) {
        ele.prepend(container);
    }

}
};
```

[I tossed all the code on this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xueye/tJnwa/3/), I am not hiding my elements at any point. When you select any combination of Categories/Reports the second step will automatically pop up below the first. The datepicker (input 1) will appear just fine (ignore the lack of CSS for a moment).

However, [when I attempt to have each step show up at the proper time](http://jsfiddle.net/xueye/VHBU8/6/) by hiding and showing the containers, the datepicker will not appear. The actual input element has "hasDatePicker" class, so I know that the datepicker is still being implemented. The actual datepicker element that's hidden shows up in Firebug's HTML viewer, too; so I know it's there.

### Hiding

#### HTML

```
        <div class="widgetcontent stdform stdform2 stdformwidget" data-bind="slideVisible: (step() == 1)" id="tmptest1">
            <p class="par">
                <label for="report_name">Title:</label>
                <span class="field">
                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: title" class="longinput" id="report_name" />
                </span>
            </p>
            <p class="par">
                <label for="report_cat">Category:</label>
                <span class="field">
                    <select data-bind="options: reportTypes, optionsText: 'title', value: selectedReportType, optionsCaption: 'Report Category'" id="report_cat" class="longinput"></select>
                </span>
            </p>
            <p class="par">
                <label for="report">Report:</label>
                <span class="field">
                    <select data-bind="options: reportPool, optionsText: 'title', value: selectedReport, optionsCaption: 'Select Report'" id="report" class="longinput"></select>
                </span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="widgetcontent stdform stdform2 stdformwidget" id="tmptest" data-bind="wizardInputs: inputPool, slideVisible: (step() == 2)">
        </div>
```

#### SlideVisible Bindings

```
        ko.bindingHandlers.slideVisible = {
            init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                var ele = $(element);
                var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                ele.hide();
                if (value) ele.slideDown();
            },
            update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                var ele = $(element);
                var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

                if (value) {
                    ele.slideDown();
                }
                else {
                    ele.slideUp();
                }
            }
        };
```

I have manually played around in my console, and it seems as though the actual act of hiding and showing the containers somehow breaks my datepicker. I have been able to replicate this without the knockout through the console by hiding the element that will contain the datepicker, placing the elements in that container, and then revealing the container. The elements show up, but the datepicker will not proc.

Has anyone dealt with this before? Is there a workaround I simply have been unable to find?

Comment: I don't think you can apply datepicker on element that is not part of the DOM.
I added             if (type == "date") {
                element = $("<input type =\"text\" id=\"" + id + "\" class=\"longinput wizard-dp\" style=\"display:inline-block\" />");
                $('button').click(function() {
                    $(element ).datepicker();
                });
            }

http://jsfiddle.net/VHBU8/11/

Comment: ¿what happen with the datepicker id if you first choose the report, set the title and then press continue? i think that you have to use the click event instead of the select events...then the above solution is more viable

Comment: Of course, wow -- can't believe I made that mistake. Once I applied the datepicker after it was in the DOM, it did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't read the whole thing but why don't you try to add the field to the DOM first and then attach the datepicker?

Comment: Of course -- this did the trick. Thank you very much. I placed datepicker after I appended all the fields, and that ultimately makes it work perfectly.